# mypy error regarding complex type List[Tuple[...]?

Tags: python, debugging, mypy, python-typing

I have the fallowing code parsed by `mypy` :

```
 PointsList = List[Tuple[str, int, int]]

 def Input(S: str, X: List[int], Y: List[int]) -> PoinstList:

        inp = list()
        for tag, x, y in zip(S, X, Y):
            inp.append(tuple([tag, x, y]))

        return inp
```

After parsing it ,returns the message down bellow.

```
a.py:28: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Tuple[object, ...]]", expected "List[Tuple[str, int, int]]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So what's wrong with the definition?, **why mypy saw the returning object's type like `List[Tuple[object, ...]` instead of `List[Tuple[str, int, int]]` as shoulded be?**. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `[tag, x, y]`. Mypy does not recognize a type for "3-element list of string, int, and int". The type it computes for `[tag, x, y]` is `List[object]`, and calling `tuple` on that produces `Tuple[object, ...]`.

Instead of `tuple([tag, x, y])`, just use a tuple literal: `(tag, x, y)`.

Or skip the loop entirely: `return list(zip(S, X, Y))`